# Bash script iterating files in a directory goes into infinite loop

Tags: bash

A function from a larger script:

```
function lipo {
OUTDIR=$SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG
mkdir -p $OUTDIR
for LIBNAME in $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG-iphoneos/lib*
do
    BASELIBNAME=`basename $LIBNAME`
    OUTLIB=$OUTDIR/$BASELIBNAME
    echo lipo $BASELIBNAME for $CONFIG
    lipo $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG-iphoneos/$BASELIBNAME $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG-iphonesimulator/$BASELIBNAME -create -output $OUTLIB
done
}
```

The target directory has a few files in it, in fact here is a real example:
[image]

When I run this function, this happens:

[image]

It just very quickly loops forever on the first file... (whole screen fills up in under 1s) the `echo` is being run but nothing else - this `lipo` operation takes a second or so so for it to loop dozens of times a second, it's not running. But no errors are given.

If I run the command on a single file by hand, it seems to work fine - or if I mess it up I get an error. So two questions really...

1. Why is only the `echo` being run?
2. Regardless if the command succeeds, how can the loop keep repeating the first file in the directory forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is recursion<sup>1</sup>.

You are effectively doing:

```
foo() {
  echo something
  foo
}
```

You probably want to change the function name to something else.

---

Alternatively, you could suppress shell function lookup by saying:

```
command lipo $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG-iphoneos/$BASELIBNAME $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG-iphonesimulator/$BASELIBNAME -create -output $OUTLIB
```

instead of

```
lipo $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG-iphoneos/$BASELIBNAME $SDK_DIR/lib/$CONFIG-iphonesimulator/$BASELIBNAME -create -output $OUTLIB
```

in which case you could keep the existing function name *as is*.

Quoting `help command`:

```
Runs COMMAND with ARGS suppressing  shell function lookup, or display
information about the specified COMMANDs.  Can be used to invoke commands
on disk when a function with the same name exists.
```

---

<sup>1. recursion, *n*: See *recursion*.</sup>

Comment: Oh drat, you're right! I've been banging my head against various build scripts for two days and gone "code blind"! Originally the `lipo` command was something else, I changed it and never even noticed this problem. How embarrassing.